Is there an official repository package?
I come from Flutter, I found the site pub.dev very good which lists all the packages concerning Flutter/Dart.
I searched for Android, but couldn't find anything, do you have a site that does the same job?
I think it's a shame that there aren't any, it's very practical.

https://maven.google.com/ has all the first-party libraries, but there's no official equivalent of anything like pub.dev for Android.

@RyanM Ok Thank you

I personally use https://plugins.gradle.org/search
which contains most of the packages I need for android and Java.
But there is no official site for what you are looking for since android
native infrastructure is not based on a specific language like flutter with dart.

This looks interesting, I'll look into it, thanks for sharing
